# Laravel 5.2 - Restricting access in Controller Construct to two user groups using Middleware

Tags: laravel, middleware

I'm struggling to understand fully how the middleware works in Laravel 5+. I have a controller for users which I want to allow Admin access to all functions through middleware and then allow managers access to only a few functions. Currently the constructor looks like this at the top of the UserController

```
    $this->middleware('admin');

    $this->middleware('manager', ['only', [
        'store',
        'profile',
        'profileUpdate'
    ]]);
```

The Middleware for each is as follows:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        return redirect()->guest('/auth/login');
    }

    if (Session::get('is_admin') === 1) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return Redirect::to('/auth/login');
}
```

and Manager:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        return redirect()->guest('/auth/login');
    }

    if (Session::get('is_manager') === 1) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return Redirect::to('/auth/login');
}
```

They're both listed in Kernal.php under protected $routeMiddleware.

So I'd like managers to have access to the 'store' function so they can save new users in the system, but when I use my middleware shown at the top of this post, it just sends both admins and managers back to the route /.

Can anyone help explain exactly what the except and only do in middleware within the constructor and why one seems to cancel the other out? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

By default the middleware is applied for each method in your controller.

'Except' tells the middleware to be applied for all the methods of your controller 'except' the ones specified via the except parameter.

'Only' does the opposite, apply the middleware 'only' to the methods specified.

Regarding your code, you probable should move

```
if (!Auth::check()) {
    return redirect()->guest('/auth/login');
}
```

In a separate middlware which only check for user authenticated and then apply this middleware in your routes.php like so:

```
$router->group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    // routes that require authentication
});
```